# Show that $5\mathbb{N}+3\mathbb{N}$={$0,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,...$}.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question is from my lecture notes. What will I show? It is clear, isn't it?

So, $5\mathbb{N}+3\mathbb{N}$={$5n_{1}+3n_{2}$:$n_{1},n_{2} \in\mathbb{N}$}={$0,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,...$}.

Comment: A statement with "$\ldots$" can never be clear ... Try to show $5\Bbb N+3\Bbb N=\Bbb N\setminus\{1,2,4,7\}$

Comment: This is a special case of [Frobenius Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). Given $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ with $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, the largest integer that cannot be represented as $p\mathbb{N} + q\mathbb{N}$ is $pq - p -q$. If you can establish this, there are finitely many integers remain to check whether they are in $p\mathbb{N} + q\mathbb{N}$ or not.

Answer (score 0):

$$8=5+3$$
$$9=3+3+3$$
$$10=5+5$$
Add $\color{red}{3}$. Then
$$11=8+3=(5+3)+3$$
$$12=9+3=(3+3+3)+3$$
$$13=10+3=(5+5)+3$$
Add $\color{red}{3}$. Then
$$14=11+3$$
$$15=12+3$$
$$16=13+3$$
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the dots mean “and all natural numbers $>12$”.

First you prove that, for every $n\ge8$, you have $n\in 5\mathbb{N}+3\mathbb{N}$.

The base step is obvious: $8=5+3$.

Assume $n>8$ and that the statement is true for every $m$ with $8\le m<n$. If $n-3>8$, we are done, because by the induction hypothesis $n-3=5a+3b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and so $n=5a+3(b+1)$. Otherwise $n=9$, $n=10$ or $n=11$; but $9=3\cdot 3$, $10=5\cdot 2$ and $11=5\cdot1+2\cdot 3$.

Now you just have to check the cases $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ manually for deciding whether they belong to the set or not.

You may want to generalize the result to

> If $r,s\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd(r,s)=1$, then there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for every $n\ge k$, $n\in r\mathbb{N}+s\mathbb{N}$.

What would be the obvious candidate for $k$?